# selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar is broken?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, jar

I'm trying to use the library "selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar" in a project. The project was previously using "selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar", but I think that is too out of date for my current version of Chrome.

When I tried to switch out the old jar for the new jar, though, I started getting the Eclipse error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Archive for required library: 'mypath/lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar' in project 'BookProject' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file BookProject Build path  Build Path Problem
```

So I tried unpacking the jar with 7-zip, but in there I got the error:

```
Can not open file 'mypath/selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar' as archive
```

Is this jar actually broken, or is there something I'm missing here? If this one isn't working, does anyone know where I could find the previous version? I couldn't find that anywhere.

Comment: I'm using the jar mentioned above without problems. I downloaded it on October, 25th 2013. The build-time from the Manifest is 2013-10-18 17:14:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unable to open the jar even using 7-zip, then it's corrupt.

I'd recommend re-downloading it.  Furthermore, when using eclipse, it might be a good idea to clear your dependency cache when upgrading things.. that usually solves things.

#### Edit

I suppose that it could be possible that the jar itself is just corrupt. If that's the case, try going to https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list  and where it says `"Search: Current Downloads"` Select `"Deprecated Downloads"`

I still use
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar

Comment: I've tried redownloading it from multiple sites on Friday and today, so it seems like that isn't helping. (Although the download today was 10kb lighter, which is interesting.) And I did try deleting Eclipse's cache of bad jars, but I think it's a problem with the jar itself.

Comment: I can get it to resolve fine with 2.35.0. I'll try to send selenium a comment about this.